# Which city does chopping production go to?

Tags: civilization-6

Is the city that owns the tile? (If so, what determines tile ownership? The city that first expanded into that tile? Or if you swap that tile to a 2nd city to work, does that 2nd city work?)

Or is it the closest city? If so, what's the tie-breaker algorithm where 2 cities are equally close?

In my particular case, I'm wondering whether if Buda buys the tile in this pic, I can then chop it for Buda:

[image: tile]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Chop production always goes to the city which owns the tile.

Any tile bought within a city is automatically owned by that city, but neighboring tiles can be swapped between multiple cities by going to the screen where you can manually allocate which tiles your workers work on.

Answer (score 0):

Things can get ambiguous if you have tightly packed cities plus there is a bug.

It's good to first check Empire lens (9) and then [Manage Citizens] I you stumbled upon a bug I saw you'll see that it either won't let you swap or a tile is in a "hole" - not owned by a neighboring city but it also won't let you buy it. I didn't have the time/patience to wait and see if maybe it would eventually give it to one of the cities - just gave up on the tile and moved on.